# Android Manipulate Group Contacts

Tags: android, contacts, group-concat

I want to know how to manipulate phone contacts in group form i.e. create, edit, delete groups, add, delete, edit contacts from a particular group.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ContentProvider and [ContactsContract](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Groups.html), also checkout [the tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html) regarding working with contacts.